# Use cases for getActiveNavs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I came across the function `getActiveNavs` and `getActiveNavContainers` in ionic 2 documentation. However, I am unsure of what it does and what the actual use case for that.

What is NavContainers means? And in which case does there will be multiple Navs and NavContainers in active state. I thought there will only be one navs in active state in one instance.

Hope someone can clarify.